# pgrep command doesn't show bash script

Tags: bash

When I run a simple bash script, say `myscript.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 30
```

from the terminal, and then do `pgrep myscript.sh` I don't get any result. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably doing this:

```
pgrep myscript.sh
```

This won't show the process you're running because it is `/bin/bash` that is running your script.

You should be doing:

```
pgrep -fl myscript.sh
```

To list your process.

As per `man pgrep`:

> `-f`      Match the pattern **anywhere** in the full argument string of the process instead of just the executable name.

Answer (score 1):

Your just running your bash script, u need to use -f flag, please check [man page](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/pgrep.htm)
Check pgrep is installed in your machine. Just do `man pgrep`, if you get command not found that install the utility.

pgrep looks through the currently running processes and lists the process IDs which matches the selection criteria to stdout. All the criteria have to match.

**Example usage:**

```
pgrep name | xargs kill
```

If you use pgrep name | kill, the ouput of pgrep name is feed to stdin of kill. Because kill does not read arguments from stdin, so this will not work.

Using xargs, it will build arguments for kill from stdin. Example:

```
$ pgrep bash | xargs echo
5514 22298 23079
```